# How to edit Heroku application online?

Tags: html, css, heroku

How can I edit the application hosted on Heroku online? I need my remote HTML/CSS designer to do some layout fixes on my application hosted on the Heroku. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: provides all the files your designer needs , let him send you the final result then ,push it on heroku yourself. You cant edit your files online and expect them to be in sync with your own repository , it defeats the purpose of using a vcs , as soon as you push an new version your online edited files will be deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, your best bet might be to [Cloud9](https://c9.io) to share and edit source code. You can [deploy directly from Cloud9 to Heroku](https://docs.c9.io/docs/deploying-via-cli).

Comment: Warning: "Posterous Spaces is no longer available".

Comment: new link for deploying to heroku from cloud 9: https://docs.c9.io/docs/deploying-via-cli

Answer (score 2):

You cannot edit your application hosted on heroku online. If you have hosted your application code elsewhere on Github or Gitorious, it might be possible for your designer to make changes online there and then you can push the code to Heroku

Comment: Yes its hosted on Github. But how will he test his changes while development after editing the code online on Github.

Is there any other alternative to host an application centrally and allow designers to work on that?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no solution of the kind that you are asking for. In that case, you need to follow mpm's advice above. You can send him the HTML, CSS files and the  you will have to do the integration yourself.

Comment: can he work with git? create a second staging app on heroku for him to push to and test his changes if he cannot boot the app locally.

Comment: @kch yes, he can do that. That is the easiest way for a windows programmer to work